# Comparing string length

Tags: bash

Trying to check if the length of a string is less than 7. I figured the following code should work just fine, but its not. Whats wrong?

```
if [ ${#certid} -lt 5] ; then
echo "[!] invalid ID"
exit
fi
```

Comment: You are comparing to 5 instead of 7

Comment: Add a space before `]` so `[ ${#certid} -lt 5 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. you compare to **5** not to 7
2. you print that an id is invalid if the length of `certid` is **less than** 5 instead of if it is longer than 5. Use `gt` instead of `lt`
3. you miss a space before the closing `]`

Comment: Thanks! Adding a space solved it. Dont know why I typed 5 in the code example, but I have that covered :)